# Why doesn't local work on STDERR and STDOUT?

Tags: perl, redirect, stdout, stderr

For my upcoming PulseAudio library I want to redirect `STDERR` and `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` logically this works,

```
sub _exec {
    open (*STDERR, '>', '/dev/null');    
    open (*STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null');    
    CORE::system('pacmd', @_ ) or die $?;
```

However, this still outputs to the term....

```
sub _exec {
    local ( *STDERR, *STDOUT );
    open (*STDERR, '>', '/dev/null');    
    open (*STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null');    
    CORE::system('pacmd', @_ ) or die $?;
```

That leaves me with two questions

1. First and foremost, why am I experiencing the behavior that I'm seeing?
2. Secondly, is there a more efficient method that doesn't involve storing the old value and replacing it?

Comment: might be obvious but have you considered something like `CORE::system('pacmd &> /dev/null' ) or die $?`

Comment: @perreal there is a reason why I'm not doing that, your statement works because the argument is passed to the shell. I explicitly do not want my command passed to the shell. It seems icky to put a library up on CPAN that uses shell-exec just because I want to cloak stderr and stdout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The child writes to fd 1 and 2, yet you didn't change fd 1 and 2. You just created new Perl variables (something the child knows nothing about) with fd 3 and 4 (something the child doesn't care about).

Here's one way of achieving what you want:

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

sub _exec {
    open(local *CHILD_STDIN,  '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
    open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null') or die $!;
    my $pid = open3(
        '<&CHILD_STDIN',
        '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
        undef,  # 2>&1
        'pacmd', @_,
    );
    waitpid($pid, 0);
    die $! if $? == -1;
    die &? if $?;
}
```

`open3` is pretty low level, but it's far higher level than doing it yourself*. [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) and [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun3) are even higher level.

---

* — It takes care for forking and assigning the handles to the right file descriptors. It handles error checking, including making pre-`exec` errors in the child appear to be the launch failures they are and not errors from the executed program.

Comment: Ah, so normally `STDIN` and `STDOUT` (fd1, fd2) are inherited from the parent process. It's still that way in perl, however in Perl the `STDIN` and `STDOUT` symbols have special meaning that don't refer to the underlying architecture's locations? Is that fair to say?

Comment: I would simply say "storing a file handle in STDIN doesn't magically assign it to fd 0". That's good. Maybe it would be nice if `system` assign to the child's fd 0 the handle in STDIN, but it doesn't, and it's too late to change that.

Comment: That clarifies the *why* perfectly, could you tell just for completeness how you would store a file-handle to `fd 0`?

Comment: Actually, one more question @ikegami, how come it works without the local? How come without the local perl writes those filehandles to the logical fd? Why does the behavior differ under `local()` and should that be `perldoc -f local`?

Comment: It assumes STDIN is associated with fd 0 and does `open *STDIN, '<&', \*CHILD_STDIN` in the child process (i.e. after the `fork`).

Comment: It works because `open *STDIN, '<', ...` will reuse the same fd by virtue of being the lowest unopened fd after `open` closed it. It doesn't work with `open local *STDIN, '<', ...` because fd 0 is not getting closed.