# perl: redirect STDERR of qx()

Tags: perl, io-redirection

Why is standard error not ignored in `suspect()`?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub ok {
    return qx{ ( @_ && true ) 2> /dev/null };
}

sub ok2 {
    open(STDERR, ">", "/dev/null");
    return qx{ @_ && true };
}

sub suspect {
    local *STDERR;
    open(STDERR, ">", "/dev/null");
    return qx{ @_ && true };
}

my $cmd = "ls /nosuchfile";
print "Some output = Bad\n";
suspect($cmd);

print "No output = OK\n";
ok($cmd);
ok2($cmd);
```

Comment: I think that the global `STDERR` is associated with file descriptor 2, and when you create a local `STDERR` that's a variable which happens to have the same name and to be initialized to the same file descriptor but then evolves independently. I can't find where this is explained in the perl documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't local work on STDERR and STDOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833088/why-doesnt-local-work-on-stderr-and-stdout)